# Как включить прокси для конкретного приложения или изменить глобальный прокси сервер Windows на C#?

Tags: c#, windows, proxy, реестр

Как подключить прокси в Windows на C# с использованием логина и пароля? Мне нужно включить прокси для конкретного приложения или глобально в Windows. У меня есть следующий код на C# и он работает:

```cs
[DllImport("wininet.dll")]
public static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);
    
public const int INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39;
public const int INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37;
    
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
    regKey = regKey.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings");
    regKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
    
    regKey.SetValue("ProxyServer", "172.16.16.30:3128");
    regKey.Close();
    
    InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
    InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
    
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\netsh.exe", "winhttp import proxy source=ie");
    Process.Start(psi);
    
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Но проблема в том, что таким методом можно подключить прокси только без логина и пароля. В сети я нашла только информацию по подключению только с ID и PORT, читала данные материалы: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1939025/12888024), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025672/12888024), [3](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/web/level2/2_6.php), [4](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-atp/configure-proxy-internet).

Comment: Моежт хак через переменные окружения? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41570055/5430535

Comment: @donRumata _I have used following settings for allowing my commands at windows command prompt to use the browser proxy to access internet_ - разве это будет работать для приложений?

Comment: Не на 100% - надо пробовать. Нормальные проги смотрят в ОС и дёргают оттуда установленные настройки. Взять тот же `Хром` или `aria2c`. Я всего лишь предположил, что поведение нужного тебе софта будет предсказуемым по нормальным практикам. О, вот это можешь попробовать: https://github.com/bobo2334/sockscap64

Comment: @donRumata _смотрят в ОС и дёргают оттуда установленные настройки_ - это про реестр или как? Просто в реестре же без логина и пароля только можно записать. _О, вот это можешь попробовать_ - это же вроде обычный софт, я не нашла его сурса, так понимаю он не опенсурс, тогда чем он поможет?

Comment: Про `sockscap64` ошибка вышла, сорян - невнимательно смотрел. По поводу переменных окружения: https://aria2.github.io/manual/ru/html/aria2c.html#id11 стандартные для unix-like, виндовый софт иногда их тоже поддерживает.